Disable web hyperlinks in pdf
I'm looking to create a Python script for disabling web hyperlinks in a PDF. I've attempted to remove annotations using PyPDF2, but the output remains unchanged. I've tried several approaches, but none have successfully removed the hyperlinks.

Thanks @KJ , The problem is that I already have internal hyperlinks that I need to keep. I have to just disable the web hyperlinks.

I need to keep (https:// ..) the URL needs to appear as regular text not as hyperlink.

So there is no way to disable the hyperlinks from the web links without actually removing (https:// ....) ? :(

You can do:
cpdf -replace-dict-entry /URI -replace-dict-entry-value '"#"' in.pdf -o out.pdf
This leaves the text and its link annotation in place, but replaces the URI with one which goes nowhere.
Be careful with the quoting of '"#"' on your system - the string passed to cpdf should be "#".

Hyperlinks in HTML and PDF viewers simply need to be https://plain.text. Most but not all viewers have some means to disable such automatic hyperlinks. 
The problem will be when you wish to retain that plain text (but keep it inactive) and have no control as to which viewer is used.

The answer,
is to break the text with a white space so for example
https:/   /www.google.com will not be active
